# Multiprocessing on Pypy is threaded but only on 1 core

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pypy

I was testing running my code on Pypy, and it seems to be faster than on cPython, but if i call it with multiprocessing like i was doing on cpython, i see threads being created, but on a single core, which defeats the purpose of using Pypy.
I am running a high number of independent simulations, (no talk, no wait between them), I have a bunch of strategies, create tuples of two strategies:

```
strat_combinations = tuple(map(tuple, itertools.combinations(
    tuple((sim_params["pool_of_strats"].values())), 2)))
```

that are then passed to a pool:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=sim_params["processes_to_use"])
pool.map(run_multi_simulation, strat_combinations)
```

And executes the main script, controlling the number of processes with processes to use.

on Cpython, i get the number of processes being distributed with the number of cores as desired, on Pypy, when 8 processes are called, 8 threads are created but they all run in the same core.

I am calling the script using:

```
pypy  Multi_Simulation_LinuxV5_Totalsims_pypy.py -withmod-_multiprocessing
```

i have tried also:

```
pypy  Multi_Simulation_LinuxV5_Totalsims_pypy.py -withmod-thread withmod-_multiprocessing
```

this is run on Ubuntu 18.04, using pypy 3.6.
Is it a problem with multiprocessing, should i be doing it in another way?

Comment: That is unexpected. The distribution of threads to cores is handled by the operating system, PyPy should not interfere with the process. Could you open an issue with a complete example on [the PyPy issue tracker](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues) ?

Comment: Will do, thanks for the suggestion. I could find various examples of people on the web complaining that pypy was faster than Cpython except when multiprocessing was involved, maybe the same behaviour was happening, but they did not realize what was happening:

Comment: I think part of the problem with PyPy performance for multiprocessing is that CPython has a c implementation for _pickle, PyPy uses a pure-python one. See for instance this (unfortunately still open) issue https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/1538